# ViewSwitcher reset spinner selected position

Tags: android

I have an Activity that use a ViewSwitcher. the view switches between a list view(child #1) and another view that contains 2 spinners(child #2)

In activity onCreate using spinner.setSelection i set a specific position for spinner. Later if next view is requested i execute viewSwitcher.showNext and spinner selection is empty - it seems like the showNext resets the spinner position. i have tried to save the position and set again after showNext is called but dont works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I get a Solutions but I think it's very stupid.

you can use this.

1.set the different layout in switcher with different id.
2.repeat the adapter ,

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, cursor,
                new String[] { Structer.TITLE ,Structer.STATUS,Structer.TITLE ,Structer.STATUS}, new int[] { R.id.detail ,R.id.detailStatus,R.id.detail2,R.id.detailStatus2});

then ,you can get it.